# PHP with mPDF issue

Tags: php, css, pdf, mpdf

I'm migrating the mpdf library from 6 to mpdf 8, in PHP 7.3.21. With mpdf 6 it runs perfectly.

I'm recieving hundreds of:

```
Notice: String offset cast occurred in C:\wamp64\www\html\kontroller\vendor\mpdf\mpdf\src\Image\Bmp.php on line 93
```

I can't find a solution in web. Please help.

```
require_once __DIR__ . "/vendor/autoload.php";

$config = array(
    'mode'  => 'utf-8',
    'format'=> 'A4', 
    'default_font_size'=>'', 
    'default_font'=>'', 
    'margin_left'   =>15, 
    'margin_right'  =>10, 
    'margin_top'    =>24, 
    '$margin_bottom'=>8, 
    '$margin_header'=>2, 
    'margin_footer' =>2, 
    'orientation'   =>'P',
    'debug' => true
);

$mpdf= new \Mpdf\Mpdf($config);
$mpdf->SetDisplayMode('fullpage');

$css = file_get_contents("_css/rpt.css");

$html = mb_convert_encoding($html, 'UTF-8', 'UTF-8');

$mpdf->SetHTMLHeader($cabec,'O',true);
$mpdf->SetHTMLFooter($rodape,'O',true);

$mpdf->WriteHTML($css,1);
$mpdf->WriteHTML($html);

$mpdf->Output($ndoc.".pdf",I);'
```

Comment: In PHP Notices are not errors. They're only giving you information about something. Those notices are not the problem. Check the documentation of the library and look if they changed something in the way it works now.

Comment: This is an unhandled notice in the library. Update to the last version of mPDF (8.0.8) and if the problem persist, create an Issue at library's Github repository https://github.com/mpdf/mpdf with a code example reproducing the issue, *including* your HTML, CSS and images (as the images are probably the culprit).